# Can I manipulate a ringback tone on the fly?

Tags: android

My question is about  smartphones which run the  Android OS as I assume my request  is not possible on iOS.

I'm interested  in  manipulating a ringback tone in real time.

The ringback tone is the sound a caller hears while waiting for a phone to be answered.

In the default state when A Calls B,  B hears a ringtone and A hears a ringback tone until B answers the call.

I want to know if when B hears the ringtone he can change the ringback tone that A hears before the call is connected.

For example, let's say that when A calls B, A hears a Michael Jackson song as a ringback tone.  Is it possible to design an app that will enable B to suddenly add another layer of sound  effects to the ongoing ringback tone or to switch it in real time to a  Madonna  song  and  then to answer the call?

Thanx Avi

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible due to the same reason as [it's not possible to make an answering machine for Android](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/6JBMgqLEozM).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not a question related to any specific phone or phone-OS, it's a question of B's carrier. The tone you hear when you're waiting for an answer from your called party is not controlled by the phone of the called party, rather by their operator (the telephone company). The operator can give you some means to set a custom tone the caller will hear while trying to reach you and I could imagine that it would be theoretically possible for them to give away access to some API to change the tone in real time from an application on your phone, though I doubt that any operator does that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Ringback tones are a carrier setting, from what I understand. Based on the calling number the network will play a specific sound, instead of the standard ringing.

Unless a wireless carrier exposes an API to manipulate that feature, I don't think it's possible.

If you wanted to do it from within the application: I believe when the phone call starts your phone state is already "in call", so you can't detect when the other party has picked up. There's no use playing a sound over the speaker while you're in the call, as you couldn't detect when the other person has picked up, so you couldn't stop the song playing.